# How to populate an ASP.NET MVC 4 dropdown with database data via ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate/fill a dropdown but I can't seem to get the values I need.
The "Employee Name" dropdown does not get populated while the "Platform Group" one does.
For "Employee Name" I use POST because this method is called by another VIEW in the software so I'd rather not change it.

I tried everything I could but the values will not show in the console or in the UI.
What am I missing?

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FXM.BO.ViewModels
{
    public class NewAffiliateViewModel
    {
        public NewAffiliateViewModel()
        {
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AffiliateName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Employee { get; set; }
        public int MT4Group { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model FXM.BO.ViewModels.NewAffiliateViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateAffiliate";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create Affiliate</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4 class="hidden">NewAffiliateViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AffiliateName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AffiliateName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AffiliateName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>*@

        @*<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MT4Group, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MT4Group, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MT4Group, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">
                @FXM.BO.Strings.T("employeeName") <span class="required">
                    @***@
                </span>
            </label>
            @*<div class="col-md-4 fieldPositionCol4 select2-bootstrap-prepend">*@
            <div class="col-md-10 ">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Employee, new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, string>(), "Key", "Value"), @FXM.BO.Strings.T("ddl_select_option"), new { @class = "form-control select2-allow-clear", @placeholder = "Select Symbols" })
                <span class="help-block">
                    @FXM.BO.Strings.T("lbl_employee_description")
                </span>
            </div>
            <img id="tpLoader" src="~/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="hidden" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">
                @FXM.BO.Strings.T("lbl_Bo_TradAcc_PlatformGroup") <span class="required">
                    @***@
                </span>
            </label>
            @*<div class="col-md-4 fieldPositionCol4 select2-bootstrap-prepend">*@
            <div class="col-md-10 ">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MT4Group, new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, string>(), "Key", "Value"), @FXM.BO.Strings.T("ddl_select_option2"), new { @class = "form-control select2-allow-clear", @placeholder = "Select Symbols" })
                <span class="help-block">
                    @FXM.BO.Strings.T("platform_group_description")
                </span>
            </div>
            <img id="tpLoader" src="~/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="hidden" />
        </div>
        @*Create button*@
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="create-affiliate-button" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/CustomScripts/Common/form-helpers.js"></script>


@*<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    // document.ready function
    $(function () {
        refreshGroups();
        // selector has to be . for a class name and # for an ID
        $('#create-affiliate-button').click(function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from reloading page
            console.log("blahblahblah");


            var b = $("form").serialize();
            //var a = $("form").serializeArray();
            console.log("formvalues", b);

         $.ajax({
                url: "/en/AjaxUI/CreateAffiliate",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: b,
            },
       
                //error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                //    failMessage();
                //}
            });
        });
    });

    function refreshGroups() {
        var pltf = "MT4_LIVE";
        var out = $('#MT4Group');
        if (pltf != null && pltf !== "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/' + window.currentLangCulture + '/BOLiveForms/GetPlatformGroupByFilter',
                data: {
                    platform: pltf, currency: "", withId : true
                },
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#tpLoader').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#tpLoader').hide();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    populateDropDown(out, data);
                    //$('#recomandedGroup').show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            out.empty();
            out.append($('<option></option>').val('').html(window.defaultSelection));
        }
    }

    //GetEmployeesExcept - Method that populates the Dropdown for EmployeeName

    $(function() {
        $.validator.addMethod("regxPhone", function(value, element, regexpr) {
            return regexpr.test(value);
        }),
        $.validator.addMethod("regxEmail", function(value) {
            return /^([\w!.%+\-])+@@([\w\-])+(?:\.[\w\-]+)+$/.test(value);
        }),
        $.validator.addMethod('validEmail', function(value, element, param) {
            return valiEmailAjax($("#Email").val());
        });

        

        $('#create-affiliate-button').select2({
            theme: "bootstrap",
            ajax: {
                url: "/en/BOEmployeeAjax/GetEmployeesExcept",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: function(params) {
                    return {
                        emplId: 0,
                        t: params.term
                    }
                },
                processResults: function(data, params) {
                    return { results: data }
                }
            },
            placeholder: window.selectAnotherSupervisor,
            escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; },
            minimumInputLength: 0
        });

</script>
```

Method in the Controller (for Employee Name)

```
        [HttpPost]
        [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache10mn", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, NoStore = true)]
        public JsonResult GetEmployeesExcept(int emplId, string t, bool searchByUserId=false)
        {
            t = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t) ? String.Empty : t;
            t = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t) ? String.Empty : t;

            if (!searchByUserId)
            {
                return Json(CrmServices.GetAllEmployees()
                    .Where(w => w.Id != emplId && string.Format("{1}{0}", w.UserDetails.Fullname, w.Id).ToLower().Contains(t.ToLower()))
                    .Select(s => new { id = s.Id, text = string.Format("{1} : {0}", s.UserDetails.Fullname, s.Id) }));
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(CrmServices.GetAllEmployees()
                    .Where(w => w.UserDetails != null && int.Parse(w.UserDetails.UserID) != emplId && string.Format("{1}{0}", w.UserDetails.Fullname, w.UserDetails.UserID).ToLower().Contains(t.ToLower()))
                    .Select(s => new { id = s.UserDetails.UserID, text = string.Format("{1} : {0}", s.UserDetails.Fullname, s.UserDetails.UserID) }));
            }
        }
```

method in the Controller (for "Platform Group")

```
        public JsonResult CreateAffiliate(NewAffiliateViewModel newAffiliateViewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var res = BackOfficeServices.BoAddAffiliateUser(newAffiliateViewModel);
                //SystemServices.ResendEmail(userId);
                return Json("success");

                //return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Also, when I uncomment the code for the ajax request for "Employee Name", the "Platform group" stops being populated. When I comment it back, the "Platform group" is populated just fine.

Thank you for any response.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console?  You seem to call `.select2()` but don't seem to have included it in a `<script src="...select2.js">` or its css.

Comment: Please have a read of [mcve] - ideally you should reduce your code until only the bits relevant to the question are left.   There seems to be a lot of extra code.   eg you mention "ajax request for employee name" - but it's not immediately obvious where this is in all that code.    It's good to provide code, but in this case, perhaps there's a little too much.

Comment: Thank you freedomn-m and @Никита for your suggestions. I will try to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for : "Select2"
Here is site https://select2.org/
Read the guide, it's easy

**UPDATE 1:**
Here is [EXAMPLE](http://dotnetqueries.com/Article/159/how-to-implement-select2-with-ajax-and-json-in-asp-net-mvc) of code, that is what you need.

Comment: @TomSawyer you need 6.Data Sources -> Ajax

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? I didn't understand what you mean by:
 6.Data Sources -> Ajax. 
Thank you

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I will look it up.

Comment: @TomSawyer Ok. In that manual you need 6 step, then AJAX description. In the head of page will be "Getting Started  -  Data sources  -  Ajax (remote data)". Wait some i will give you code example in ASP.

Comment: @TomSawyer Check Update in answer please.